# MySQL select N rows under different conditions

Tags: mysql

Suppose there is a table as

```
| id | value |
|  1 |   xyz |
|  4 |   abc |
|  5 |  test |
```

I want to select `N` rows where `id` is smaller than a number `X`, but if this result set is less than `N` rows, I want following rows added to ensure there are `N` rows selected (unless there is no sufficient rows in this table).

For example, I want to get `N=2` rows where `id` is no larger than `X=4`, so I get `1st` and `2nd` rows. But If I want to get `N=3` rows for `X=4`, I want all the three rows.

Can I do this in one statement and try to be efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prioritize the rows.  You can do this using `order by` and `limit`.  Here is an example:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (x <= @X) desc, x
limit 2;
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. Didn't know order by can be used like this.